# The position does not match while overlapping the image on the map using folium

Tags: python, projection, folium

This code is draft

```
bounds_lat = np.array([34.884427, 35.389037])
bounds_lon = np.array([128.761718, 129.305605])


folium.raster_layers.ImageOverlay(image=image_path,
                                  bounds=[[bounds_lat[0], bounds_lon[0]], [bounds_lat[1], bounds_lon[1]]],                            
                                  mercator_project=True,
                                  opacity=0.3).add_to(map)
```

[image]
My image was incorrectly overlaid in map, so add the **mercator_project=True**

change the code

```
bounds_lat = np.array([34.884427, 35.389037])
bounds_lon = np.array([128.761718, 129.305605])


folium.raster_layers.ImageOverlay(image=image_path,
                                  bounds=[[bounds_lat[0], bounds_lon[0]], [bounds_lat[1], bounds_lon[1]]],
                                  mercator_project=True,
                                  opacity=0.3).add_to(map)
```

error occurred
[image]
please help me

Comment: Can you provide the image you want to overlay on the map? We can load it from a local file, or maybe an image on a URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading [the docs](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/modules.html) yielded the following:

> image (string, file or array-like object) – The data you want to draw on the map. * If string, it will be written directly in the output file. * If file, it’s content will be converted as embedded in the output file. * If array-like, it will be converted to PNG base64 string and embedded in the output.

This means you can use both a `path` to an image or an `image array`:

But for `mercator_project` the documentation says:

> mercator_project (bool, default False.) – Used only for array-like image. Transforms the data to project (longitude, latitude) coordinates to the Mercator projection. Beware that this will only work if image is an array-like object.

So you must first load the image into an `array`:

```
from PIL import Image

image_array= Image.open(image_path)
```

Or use any other image processing library (`OpenCV` eg.).

Then you can do:

```
folium.raster_layers.ImageOverlay(image=image_array,
                                  bounds=[[bounds_lat[0], bounds_lon[0]], [bounds_lat[1], bounds_lon[1]]],
                                  mercator_project=True,
                                  opacity=0.3).add_to(map)
```